# IText: NullPointerException on setGenerateAppearances

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF using a PDF template and fields to modify.
The NullPonterException is on the method setGenerateAppearances. If I comment that method call, I don't get the exception anymore, nut my fields are not filled anymore.
This method did not give exceptions with a previous PDF template.
My itextpdf version is 5.5.5.

```
public static PdfReader fillFields(Map<String,String> data, String templateFileName, int page, boolean failOnNotFound) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateFileName);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
        fields.setGenerateAppearances(true); // <-- NullPointerException
        LinkedHashMap<String,FieldInfo> lhm = orderedNames(fields);

        for( String fieldName : lhm.keySet() ){
            String key = page + ":" + fieldName;
            if(data.containsKey(key)){
                String value = data.get(key);
                FieldInfo fi = lhm.get(fieldName);
                setField( value, fi, page, fields );
            }else if( data.containsKey(fieldName) ){
                String value = data.get(fieldName);
                FieldInfo fi = lhm.get(fieldName);
                setField( value, fi, page, fields );                
            }else{
                if(failOnNotFound){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Template field " + fieldName + " not found on page " + page + " data= " + data.toString() );
                }
            }
        }


        stamper.setAnnotationFlattening(true);
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

        // per verifica del risultato
        FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream("pdf_" + page + ".pdf");
        fw.write(baos.toByteArray());
        fw.close();
```

return new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    }

The exact point of the exception is:

```
public void setGenerateAppearances(boolean generateAppearances) {
    this.generateAppearances = generateAppearances;
    PdfDictionary top = reader.getCatalog().getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
    if (generateAppearances)
        top.remove(PdfName.NEEDAPPEARANCES);
    else
        top.put(PdfName.NEEDAPPEARANCES, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.setGenerateAppearances(AcroFields.java:1829)
    at org.mycompany.GeneratePdfTest.fillFields(GeneratePdfTest.java:218)
    at org.mycompany.GeneratePdfTest.test3(GeneratePdfTest.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sounds like your PDF isn't a real form. Can you share your PDF?

Comment: Yes, unless something is extremely weird, the only apparent possible cause for a `NullPointerException` there is the absnce of the **AcroForm** dictionary. An `if (top != null)` there would be appropriate.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Indeed, it was a problem linked to the PDF template